# Implementing SMSplugin getting error: Uncaught ReferenceError: sms is not defined

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I am using  [this SMS Plugins](https://github.com/aharris88/phonegap-sms-plugin) for my android application but I when I am running the app in AVD LogCat is giving me this error in `green` and `blue` color : `Uncaught ReferenceError: sms is not defined` . and it is not executing the success or error function.

Please help me to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

```
submitSMSClick = function() {
        alert("click");
        var name = document.getElementById("nameSMS").value;
        var number = "09475641021";
        var message = name + ": " + $("#messageSMS").val();
        var intent = "INTENT";
        //leave empty for sending sms using default intent
        var success = function() {
            alert('Message sent successfully');
        };
        var error = function(e) {
            alert('Message Failed:' + e);
        };
        sms.send(number, message, intent, success, error);
};
```

Comment: where the `sms` is present. Show some code..

Comment: I have edited the question with the code

Comment: are you added sms.js in your html and your sms plugin in config .xml

Comment: no I have installed the plugin using CLI ie. `phonegap add plugin `

Comment: ok good. what about sms.js

Comment: do I have to include sms.js, I thought that the CLI command take care of all this

Comment: check is that present in your html or not..if it is not present include and give the required permissions

Answer (score -1, accepted):

All one need to do is to include the `sms.js` file present inside `www/plugins/org.apache.cordova.plugin.sms/` with his main html file.

Comment: If the cordova sms plugin is used, then why are we adding the SMS.js to the index?